# Determine if the cursor is on the first/last character of word

Tags: cursor

How to determine if the cursor is placed on the last character of the word under the cursor?

I can get information about the word under cursor like determining if the length of the word under the cursor is 1 character:

```
strlen(expand('<cword>'))==1
```

But as far as I see the expression `expand('<cword>')` only returns the word itself with no information about the cursor position.

Any help pointing towards a potential solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a more experimental approach that @Karl Yngve Lervåg does in [his answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18139/343):

This works by moving the cursor back a word and then forwards again and then seeing if the cursor is in the same place. If it is, then the cursor was on the end of a `<word>`.

Using this technique saves you having to reverse-engineer and reimplement Vim's `<word>` algorithm in VimScript.

```
function! EndWord() abort
  let pos = getpos('.')
  normal! gee
  if pos == getpos('.')
    return v:true
  else
    call setpos('.', pos)
    return v:false
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this answer. Tested it and it seems to work for what I had in mind.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

I would get the characters on the current line from the cursor and on and check if they match the end-of-word atom, i.e. something like this:

```
map <silent> q :call Test()<cr>

function! Test() abort
  return strcharpart(getline('.'), virtcol('.')-1, 3) =~# '^\w\>'
endfunction
```

Here I've added a map for making it easy to test. You can adjust the function, resource the file and then use `q` to test the function.

I use `virtcol` and `strcharpart` to support multibyte characters.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it definitely goes in the right direction. One thing that I am still missing (and it is my fault for not specifying it in the question) is - it doesn't work on non-word characters, like `:` or `)`. Maybe you have any quick pointers about how to make it behave in-tune with vim's `word` motion definition? I tried replacing `\w` with `\k` in your example, but it didn't help: when the cursor is on a loose ":" for example - it doesn't consider that a "word".

Comment: It's a bit unclear exactly what you want to consider a word. Do you want to adhere to `:help word`? Or perhaps `:help WORD`? The first thing to try is to change `\w` with `\S`, i.e. any non space character.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yep, I would like to adhere to `:word` or in other words - any character where vim's `e` motion stops on should return "1" for the "end of word" test. I found that there is `\k` for "iskeyword" but it didn't get me anywhere.